# Nested Sort in Struct Array in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here its my model looks like

```
struct ContactModel{
    var alphabet: String
    var users: [UserModel]
}

struct UserModel{
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
}
```

Using `sort` alphabetically sorting working fine here Is the code:

```
contactArray.sort{ $0.alphabet < $1.alphabet }
```

Now, I want to sort ascending or descending order on bases of `UserModel` `firstname`
I try with nested sorting but giving me different errors like

```
Comparable and Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two '[UserModel]' operands
```

I search on StackOverflow regarding this but haven't find nested sorting and operands error solution.

I tried this way

```
let sortedStudents = contactArray.sorted { (lhs: ContactModel, rhs: ContactModel) -> Bool in
                let users1 = lhs.users.sorted(by: {
                    $0.firstname.lowercased() < $1.firstname.lowercased()
                })
                let users2 = rhs.users.sorted(by: {
                    $0.firstname.lowercased() < $1.firstname.lowercased()
                })
                
                return users1 < users2
            }
```

But its not working. The only problem here that I am not able to do nested sort here want to sort firstname of UserModel and the We have `ContactModel` Array

```
var contactArray = [ContactModel](){
        didSet{
            
            contactArray.sort{ $0.alphabet < $1.alphabet } //Simple Sort working fine.
            
            let sortedStudents = contactArray.sorted { (lhs: ContactModel, rhs: ContactModel) -> Bool in
                let users1 = lhs.users.sorted(by: {
                    $0.firstname.lowercased() < $1.firstname.lowercased()
                })
                let users2 = rhs.users.sorted(by: {
                    $0.firstname.lowercased() < $1.firstname.lowercased()
                })
                
                return users1 < users2
            }
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Array Contains this

```
 func getAllContacts() -> [ContactModel]{
        return [
            ContactModel(alphabet: "B", users: [
                UserModel(firstname: "Bhaswar", lastname: "Patel"),
                UserModel(firstname: "Bunty", lastname: "Patel")
            ]),
            ContactModel(alphabet: "N", users: [
                UserModel(firstname: "Nilesh", lastname: "Darji")
            ]),
            ContactModel(alphabet: "Y", users: [
                UserModel(firstname: "Yogesh", lastname: "Patel"),
                UserModel(firstname: "Yash", lastname: "Patel")
            ])
        ]
    }
```

Results:

Alphabetic section sorting working fine need to sort users now using firstname for this `Yash` is comes first then `Yogesh`

[image]

Any suggestion appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to sort the `users` array, not the `contactArray`? Can you show your desired result?

Comment: I want to sort users firstname but I have contact array. Yes showing result

Comment: Please check updated. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I'm not asking about what you want to sort _by_. I'm asking which array you want to change. Your desired result seems to be the same as what the array contains originally? Do you perhaps mean that you want "Yash" to come before "Yogesh"?

Comment: Yes Here we have contact array first I sorted using alphabet and then we need to sort the contact users on bases of firstname. Yes first comes Yash then Yogesh. The same thing for all section users. contacts.users.sort firstname like this!

Comment: No its not working! IF I do that then user1 and user2 show me the error that was never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is sorting the `ContactModel` array based on the alphabet first. Then, it maps this sorted array to a new array where the `UserModel` array is sorted as well.

```swift
contactArray.sort { $0.alphabet < $1.alphabet }
let fullySorted = contactArray.map( { ContactModel(alphabet: $0.alphabet, users: $0.users.sorted { $0.firstname < $1.firstname }) } )
```

The `map` and `sort` functions could also be swapped, i.e. first mapping to a new array and then sorting based on the alphabet.
The original array:

```swift
var contactArray = [
    ContactModel(alphabet: "B", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Bhaswar", lastname: "Patel"),
        UserModel(firstname: "Bunty", lastname: "Patel")
    ]),
    ContactModel(alphabet: "N", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Nilesh", lastname: "Darji")
    ]),
    ContactModel(alphabet: "Y", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Yogesh", lastname: "Patel"),
        UserModel(firstname: "Yash", lastname: "Patel")
    ])
]
```

will become (Yash and Yogesh are now alphabetically ordered):

```swift
var contactArray = [
    ContactModel(alphabet: "B", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Bhaswar", lastname: "Patel"),
        UserModel(firstname: "Bunty", lastname: "Patel")
    ]),
    ContactModel(alphabet: "N", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Nilesh", lastname: "Darji")
    ]),
    ContactModel(alphabet: "Y", users: [
        UserModel(firstname: "Yash", lastname: "Patel"),
        UserModel(firstname: "Yogesh", lastname: "Patel")
    ])
]
```

If there would be another `ContactModel` with `alphabet = "A"`, then this would've been the first one in the `contactArray`.

You *could* even reduce it to a single line of code if you really want. However, I wouldn't recommend it because sorting, and mapping can become hard to read quite easily for people that aren't familiar with it.

```swift
// Single line of code solution (I wouldn't recommend this because of readability)
let fullySorted = contactArray.sorted { $0.alphabet < $1.alphabet }.map( { ContactModel(alphabet: $0.alphabet, users: $0.users.sorted { $0.firstname < $1.firstname }) } )
```

Comment: Aww! Great understood! so now I have to assign this fullSorted to my contactArray?

Comment: You could do this immediately (i.e. replace `let fullySorted` by `contactArray`), assuming it's a `var` and not a `let`.